# Divide sheets among diferent people

Tags: excel, vba

So i have multiple sheets with information on them.  i need to divide these sheets evenly among multiple people.  But i need to divide it by the length of the list. For Example:
Sheet 1 has 15 Rows
Sheet 2 has 41 Rows
Sheet 3 has 32 Rows

Totals Rows is 88 if i have 5 people that would be 17.6 per person.  round to the integer would be 17 per person.  so what i'm looking for it to do is divide by sheet and row. Example:
Person 1 would get Sheet 1 Rows 1-15 and Sheet 2 Rows 1 and 2
Person 2 would get Sheet 2 Rows 3-20
etc...

here is what i have so far.

```
Staff = InputBox("How many people will this be divided among?", "Split")
ReDim Person(1 To Staff)
ReDim SNarray(1 To Sheets.Count)
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    SNarray(i) = Sheets(i).Name
Next
ReDim RowCounts(1 To Sheets.Count)
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(SNarray(i)).Activate
    RowCounts(i) = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Next
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Total = Total + RowCounts(i)
Next
Total = (Total - 2) / Staff
Total = Int(Total)
```

Comment: I dont see why you need to loop three times over the same sheets.

Comment: How would staff "get" a row? and what's the significance of the `-2` ?

Comment: So i haven't started to slim it down yet, still new to coding for vba, but i'm just at the start point for it.

As for the -2 it is to remove the titles in the first row.  so the actually data starts at row 2 on each page.

Comment: For the "get" a row, that will be later on when i populate an email.  it would list each sheet and row for each person

Comment: Would it be easier here to first combine all the sheets into one?

Comment: I would love to be able to, but i have to keep the pages separated otherwise it creates to many issues issues down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, i As Integer, Staff As Integer

    Staff = InputBox("How many people will this be divided among?", "Split")

    For i = 1 To Staff
        Set Ws = Sheets(i)
        With Ws
            r = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Total = Total + r - 1
        End With
    Next
    Total = Total / Staff
    Total = Int(Total)
    MsgBox Total
End Sub
```